# Change tool color with named colors

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, colors

I created an enum with some of the named colors we can find in Visual Studio.
I would like to assign them to an ellipse (WPF tool), but I can't find how to do.

Here is my code :

```
public enum Color_light
{
    None,
    GhostWhite,
    Yellow,
    AliceBlue,
    OrangeRed,
    Red
}

public Color_light light_color
{
    get { return light_color; }
    set
    {
        light_color = value;

        lumiere.Fill = [...]
    }
}
```

Lumiere is the name of my ellipse.

Comment: `Ellipse.Fill` is type of `Brush`, so you cannot assign your custom class/enum value to it. You need to create new `Brush` instance and assign that created instance to it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, so i'll try this :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Color col = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(light_color.ToString());
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(col);
lumiere.Fill = brush;
```